# How to commit/write data after each chunk when downloading a file so that it does not use all memory out?

Tags: python, windows

I can see that the Memory is being consumed for storage when I download a file. Is there a way to commit the data after each chunk of 1GB data downloaded?

[image: Memory Usage can reach to 90%]

```
submission_path = r'D:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Reddit Data\ETL-Python\\'
for download_file in clean_matching_list_of_href:
    save_file_w_submission_path = submission_path + download_file
    constructured_url = url_to_download + download_file
    request = urllib.request.Request(constructured_url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    data_content = response.read()
    shutil.copyfileobj(save_file_w_submission_path,data_content,length = 10000)
```

**Update:**
So I have used the write instead as follows:

```
for download_file in matching_list_of_href:
    filename = download_file[download_file.rfind("/")+1:]
    save_file_w_submission_path = path_to_save_document + filename
    request = urllib.request.Request(download_file)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    data_content = response.read()
    with open(save_file_w_submission_path, 'wb') as wf:    
        wf.write(data_content)
    print(save_file_w_submission_path)
```

Comment: Do you mean after each "chunk" written by `copyfileobj()`? Also, setting `length` to a smaller value might help.

Comment: The `length` does not seem to work. I meant that after each 1GB amount, the downloaded data is merged with the available data. Download 1GB, create the file. Download 1GB more, merge it with the 1GB already existing and etc...

Comment: The docs say both the first and second arguments passed to `copyfileobj()` should be "file-like" objects and I just noticed that `save_file_w_submission_path` isn't one, it's a string.

Comment: The `save_file_w_submission_path` is the path file I want to create the object. For example: `D:\Download\WebContent.bz2` Is this correct way to use `copyfileobj()` . I think the open file should not be there. I have updated my post

Comment: I don't think that's the correct way to use it. From the documentation and the source code, it sounds/looks like both arguments should be open files.Here's the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/shutil.py)).